# pyodbc.connect() to SQL Server database fails

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, database, pyodbc

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server database with via `pyodbc.connect()`.

My connection string is the following:

```
connection = pyodbc.connect(
     "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=server;DATABASE=databaseP;UID=user;PWD=password"
)
```

but it fails over and over again, and I get the following error:

> '42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot open database "database" requested by the login. The login failed. (4060) (SQLDriverConnect)

I tried to escape anything, what appeared to me as a possible problem (e.g. _ or @), but to no avail.

After I entered the very same data via DSN, and used the following connection string, it worked:

```
connection = pyodbc.connect(
    dsn="my_dsn",
    uid=user,
    pwd=password
)
```

What is wrong with the first connection string? I would rather (for personal reasons) use the first one, but still cannot find out, why it's not working.

Comment: Please show the full error message from the SQL Server log (it contains more info than what you get from the client app). Is this a SQL Server Authentication login or a Windows Authentication login that is failing?

Comment: Use SSMS and attempt to connect to the same instance with those same credentials and access the same database. Does it work?

Comment: @Charlieface: Here is the full message I get after running the script: Exception has occurred: ProgrammingError
('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot open database "XXXXX" requested by the login. The login failed. (4060) (SQLDriverConnect); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot open database "XXXXX" requested by the login. The login failed. (4060)'). This is a SQL Server Authentification login, I assume, as the trusted_connection is set to "no"

Comment: @Smor: Unfortunately, I'm not able to, as I'm doing it on my working laptop, and do not have any permissions to install SSMS

Comment: Those aren't the errors from the SQL Server logs, Viont, that @Charlieface asked for. SQL Server logs certainly don't report "programming errors". That's clearly from python.

Comment: If you have another way of logging in, do `EXEC sys.xp_readerrorlog`

Comment: @Larnu: My apologies for confusion. As I do not have any "direct" access to the SQL Server - is there any possibility for me to get hold of the server log?

Comment: Sounds like you need to speak to your DBA for connection troubleshooting first.

Comment: @Charlieface: I tried right now to execute it, by I got the "Permission denied" message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you connect without specifying a database you connect to the login's DEFAULT_DATABASE, which is typically Master.

If you specify a database in your connection string you will connect directly to that database.  And if the requested database doesn't exist, or you don't have access to it you get the error: "Cannot open database "XXXXX" requested by the login. The login failed. "

Comment: Hi @David Browne - thanks a lot for the hint. After commenting out the line with the database name, I was able to connect via the connection string